# Adding a new XML Element after a specific but not defined position in an exisiting XML File in python

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I want to add a new XML Element to an existing XML File. The problem is that the Position varies from file to file but I want to insert my new Element always behind the last Tag of a specific element. So let's say I have X amount of `<Data>` Tags in the file and after the last `<Data>` Tag I want to create and insert a new XML Element with a `<Example>` Tag.

Here is my code so far:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET


xml_file = "example.xml"


tree = ET.parse(xml_file)
root = tree.getroot()

LastDataTag = root.findall('.//Data')[-1]

new_element = ET.Element('Example')

root.insert(LastDataTag + 1, new_element)
```

The Problem I see is that I don't get an integer as a return form findall, but rather a Postion within the file like this `<Element 'Data' at 0x000001E99BE7A610>` I get that this is obviously not working because python cant add +1 to this since it's not an integer.

Is there a way to translate this to an integer so you can work with it this way or is there another way of doing this or getting the index of the last `<Data>` Tag? The other posts I looked at did it the same way with the insert method but they all had a fixed index number that did not change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're able to use lxml instead of ElementTree, it has the method [`addnext()`](https://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree._Element-class.html#addnext) that makes it much easier to add a following sibling...

```py
from lxml import etree

xml_file = 'example_input.xml'
tree = etree.parse(xml_file)

last_data_elem = tree.findall('.//Data')[-1]
new_element = etree.Element('Example')
last_data_elem.addnext(new_element)

tree.write('example_output.xml')
```

If you're stuck with ElementTree, you'll first have to find the parent of the `Data` element so you can determine its index. Then you can use `.insert()` with the index plus one...

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml_file = 'example_input.xml'

tree = ET.parse(xml_file)
root = tree.getroot()

last_data_elem = root.findall('.//Data')[-1]
new_element = ET.Element('Example')

for data_parent in root.findall('.//*[Data]'):
    for data_elem in data_parent.findall('Data'):
        if data_elem is last_data_elem:
            data_index = list(data_parent).index(data_elem)
            data_parent.insert(data_index + 1, new_element)

tree.write('example_output.xml')
```

Comment: Thanks this worked out great! I find the lxml Library way easier to manage than the Standard ElementTree. I ended up rewriting my whole code with lxml instead of ElementTree

Comment: @LooseJaguar - Excellent choice. It also has better xpath 1.0 support. I rarely use `.find()` or `.findall()` and instead use `.xpath()` most of the time.